# Executing JAR File on Amazon Web Services Elastic Beanstalk Node.js

Tags: java, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, child-process

I am running the following in node.js on my Elastic Beanstalk AWS instance:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var child = exec('java -cp my.jar com.whatever.my.Class -t param1 -u param2'),
function (error, stdout, stderr)
{
    logger.info(error);
    logger.info(stdout);
    logger.info(stderr);
});
```

I am getting the following error message:

"Could not find or load main class com.whatever.my.Class"

However I know my jar file is fine because when I run the java command the same way in Terminal it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Well it helps if you don't include .jar in your .gitignore file.  The jar was never getting uploaded to the AWS server!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to pass you $PATH to the exec, like:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var child = exec('java -cp my.jar com.whatever.my.Class -t param1 -u param2', {env: process.env}),
function (error, stdout, stderr)
{
    logger.info(error);
    logger.info(stdout);
    logger.info(stderr);
});
```